# ISP Bandwidth Limitations

Tags: anonymity, internet-service-provider

If this has been answered, I can't find it. So, please have patience. My ISP limits the amount of data I may receive in a month. If I am using Tor, can the ISP measure how much data I am receiving?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, most likely. Your traffic passed through your ISP regardless of whether or not you use tor. They will likely simply measure the traffic going to your IP even if its encrypted or not.

Comment: it can also be a little bit more traffic with Tor because of the additional encryption layers, but depending on your browser-settings (blocking java script, ads etc.) it may even be less traffic as with a normal browser. - the higher the security level, the more gets usually blocked.